# Property 'filter' does not exist on type '{}

Tags: angular6

I have an object like this after query. I need to filter it based on the year.

This is my object.

```
(6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
 0: {title: "PERSONAL", subtitle: "The standard version", description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit", year: "2018", …}
    1: {title: "STUDENT", subtitle: "Most popular choice", description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit", year: "2017", …}
    2: {title: "BUSINESS", subtitle: "For the whole team", description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit", year: "2018", …}
```

I used following code to filter.

```
users = {};
ngOnInit() {
    this.users.filter((user) => user.year == '2018');
}
```

But I get am getting `error TS2339: Property 'filter' does not exist on type '{}'.`

Can anybody help me how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

If your already assigning above object to Users.

```
users: any;
users =[{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}];
```

then remove this line

```
// users = {}; remove this line it will work
ngOnInit() {
  this.users.filter((user) => user.year == '2018');
}
```

your assigning object when it has been already an Array variable

Answer (score 0):

users is of type object.
filter method support only in the array object

Also, where is this.user is initialized?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot apply `filter` on object

```
users = [ {year: '2000'}, {year: '2018'} ];
ngOnInit() {
    this.users.filter((user) => user.year == '2018');
}
```

This will work